# WMS GetCapabilities format does not return a wms content

Tags: geoserver, wms, getcapabilities

My geoserver WMS GetCapabilities request returns an XML file download popup. But I want to see xml result on my browser. And I want to request via ajax request. But could not.

WMS Get capabilities like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE WMT_MS_Capabilities SYSTEM "http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.1.1/capabilities_1_1_1.dtd" >

<WMT_MS_Capabilities version="1.1.1">
  <Service>
    <Name>OGC:WMS</Name>
    <Title>Web Map Service</Title>
    <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://.."/>
  </Service>
  <Capability>
    <Request>
      <GetCapabilities>
        <Format>application/vnd.ogc.wms_xml</Format>
        <DCPType>
          <HTTP>
            <Get>
              <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://..."/>
            </Get>
          </HTTP>
        </DCPType>
      </GetCapabilities>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WMS till version 1.1.1 is using mime type application/vnd.ogc.wms_xml. Set your system to open such documents with a browser or use WMS 1.3.0 that is using mime type that is understood by browsers automatically.

Compare

http://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities

vs.

http://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.1&request=GetCapabilities

Comment: Version 1.3.0 does not work that requested source. So is this a geoserver problem?

Comment: Oh sorry, my requested link is Gowebcache capability service. I noticed now.